# How to get file_get_contents() warning instead of the PHP error?

Tags: php

```
file_get_contents('https://invalid-certificate.com');
```

Yields the following PHP warning and error:

> **PHP warning:** Peer certificate CN='*.invalid-certificate.net' did not match expected CN='invalid-certificate.com'
>
> **PHP error:** file_get_contents(https://invalid-certificate.com): failed to open stream: operation failed

---

I want to use exceptions instead of the PHP warning, so:

```
$response = @file_get_contents('https://invalid-certificate.com');

if ($response === false) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    throw new \Exception($error['message']);
}
```

But now the exception message is:

> file_get_contents(https://invalid-certificate.com): failed to open stream: operation failed

That's normal, `error_get_last()` returns **the last error**…

How can I get the warning, which contains much valuable information regarding the failure?

Comment: CURL is best to handling errors instead of `file_get_contents()`

Comment: @jogesh_pi Yes I know, I want to know for `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make good use of **[set_error_handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler)** and convert those errors into exceptions and use exceptions properly

```
<?php
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, array $errcontext) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
});

try {
  $response = file_get_contents('https://invalid-certificate.com');
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
  var_dump($e);   // ofcourse you can just grab the desired info here
}
?>
```

A much simpler version would be

```
<?php
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr) {
    var_dump($errstr);
});
$response = file_get_contents('https://invalid-certificate.com');
?>
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/294865)**

Comment: That's really a "bring out the big guns" solution, I'd rather use a simpler alternative if it exists

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli I think you should "bring out the big guns" because at your script level you can get only the last error, without such error handler.